# NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance and pref panes

Tags: nspreferencepane, macos-darkmode

I have a System Preferences Pane that always opens in the light appearance mode when running in 10.14. Normal apps compiled in earlier system can use dark mode by including a plist parameter: NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance = NO.

However, when I add this key to my Info.plist in the pref pane, nothing happens.

How can a custom System Preferences pane open in dark mode when dark mode is active on 10.14? Apple's default panes do and there is no key in those plists that seems to enable it.